# Change background color of current child page on side menu

Tags: html, css, dotnetnuke

Am trying to change the background color of the child in my side menu but i didnt find a way yet to do this. This css i use is inside a module i have in my site and the site its for Dotnetnuke.

Here is the css :

```
<style>
    menu{
    padding-left:24px;
}

ul.menu_sx {
    width: 172px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Lucida Grande; 
}

ul.menu_sx li {    
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.menu_sx li a {    
    padding: 8px 24px 8px 8px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
    text-align: left;
    color: #333;
}

ul.menu_sx a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #FEEE9D;
    color: #996600;
}

ul.menu_sx li a span {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}

/* MENU SECONDO LIVELLO -> voce con submenu associato */
ul.menu_sx ul{
    #margin-top:-19px;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul.menu_sx li.segue a,
ul.menu_sx li.segue_2 a {
    background-image: url(/dnn7/Portals/0/menu/BlackArrowRight.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 1px -1px;
}

/* elementi annidati secondo livello */
.menu_sx_sublevel li a
{
    background-image: none;
}

ul.menu_sx li.segue a:hover,
ul.menu_sx li.segue_2 a:hover {
    background-image: url(/dnn7/Portals/0/menu/BrownArrowRight.gif);
}

/* MENU SECONDO LIVELLO -> menu attivo */
ul.menu_sx li.active,
ul.menu_sx li.active_menu_yellow,
ul.menu_sx li.active_menu_2_yellow{

}

ul.menu_sx li.active a,
ul.menu_sx li.active_menu_yellow a,
ul.menu_sx li.active_menu_2_yellow a{
    padding-top: 9px;
    background: url("/dnn7/Portals/0/menu/BrownArrowDown.gif") 1px -1px #feee9d no-repeat;
    color: #996600;
    background-color: #fee35b;
}

/* MENU SECONDO LIVELLO -> menu aperto */
ul.menu_sx li.active_menu a,
ul.menu_sx li.active_menu_2 a{
    background: url(/dnn7/Portals/0/menu/BlackArrowDown.gif) no-repeat 155px 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

ul.menu_sx li.active_menu a:hover,
ul.menu_sx li.active_menu_2 a:hover,
ul.menu_sx li.active_menu_yellow a:hover,
ul.menu_sx li.active_menu_2_yellow a:hover {
    background: url("/dnn7/Portals/0/menu/BrownArrowDown.gif") 1px -1px #feee9d no-repeat;
    color: #996600;
    background-color: #fee35b;
}

/* MENU SECONDO LIVELLO -> submenu 2 livello*/
ul.menu_sx li ul li {
    border-bottom: none;
}

ul.menu_sx li ul li a {
    color: #996600;
    background: none !important;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

ul.menu_sx li ul li.segue a,
ul.menu_sx li ul li.segue_2 a{
    background-image: url("/dnn7/Portals/0/menu/BrownArrowRight.gif");
    background-position: 1px -1px;
}

ul.menu_sx li ul li.active_menu a,
ul.menu_sx li ul li.active_menu_2 a,
ul.menu_sx li ul li.active_menu_yellow a,
ul.menu_sx li ul li.active_menu_2_yellow a{
    background: url("/dnn7/Portals/0/menu/BrownArrowDown.gif") 1px -1px #FFF9D9 no-repeat;
}

ul.menu_sx li ul li.active_menu a:hover,
ul.menu_sx li ul li.active_menu_2 a:hover,
ul.menu_sx li ul li.active_menu_yellow a:hover,
ul.menu_sx li ul li.active_menu_2_yellow a:hover{
    background-position: 1px -1px;
}

/*fix luca 14/08/2014*/
ul.menu_sx li.active {
    background-color: #fee35b !important;
    color: #996600;
    font-weight: bold;
    /*padding: 9px 24px 8px 8px;*/
}

ul.menu_sx li ul li.active {
    /*padding-left:16px;*/
}

ul.menu_sx li ul li ul li.active {
    padding-left:24px;
}

.current > a
{
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}

.menu_sx li ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #FEEE9D !important;
}

</style>
```

And here are my classes.. 
ul ID: menusx,
ul Class: menu_sx,
li Class: menu,
Sublevel ul Class: menu_sx_sublevel,
Active Class: current

I tried adding the background color to .current, i tried creating some new quoted paragraphs{} but still no luck.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
**Here is the html of the side menu**

```
<div>
   <ul id="menusx" class="menu_sx">
      <li class="menu active_menu_yellow">
         <a href="http://localhost/dnn7/Automotive-Lubricants/Engine-Oils">Engine Oils</a>
         <ul class="menu_sx_sublevel" style="display: block;">
            <li class=""><a href="http://localhost/dnn7/Automotive-Lubricants/Engine-Oils/Cars-Vans">Cars &amp; Vans</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="http://localhost/dnn7/Automotive-Lubricants/Engine-Oils/Trucks">Trucks</a></li>
            <li class="current active_menu_yellow"><a href="http://localhost/dnn7/Automotive-Lubricants/Engine-Oils/Motorbikes">Motorbikes</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="http://localhost/dnn7/Automotive-Lubricants/Engine-Oils/Marine">Marine</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="http://localhost/dnn7/Automotive-Lubricants/Engine-Oils/Stationary-Engines">Stationary Engines</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu segue">
         <a href="http://localhost/dnn7/Automotive-Lubricants/Transmission-Oil">Transmission Oil</a>
         <ul class="menu_sx_sublevel" style="display: none;">
            <li class=""><a href="http://localhost/dnn7/Automotive-Lubricants/Transmission-Oil/Automatic-Transmission">Automatic Transmission</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="http://localhost/dnn7/Automotive-Lubricants/Transmission-Oil/Manual-Transmission">Manual Transmission</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu segue">
         <a href="http://localhost/dnn7/Automotive-Lubricants/Special-Automotive-Products">Special Automotive Products</a>
         <ul class="menu_sx_sublevel" style="display: none;">
            <li class=""><a href="http://localhost/dnn7/Automotive-Lubricants/Special-Automotive-Products/Antifreeze">Antifreeze</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="http://localhost/dnn7/Automotive-Lubricants/Special-Automotive-Products/Brake-Fluid">Brake Fluid</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML as well.

Comment: there is no html. Its dotnetnuke website. I could share the script of the module if that will be helpfull

Comment: Without the HTML, we would just be guessing and unable to provide you with the best help possible. If you can't find the HTML file that's controlling your sidebar, try right-clicking on the page, select "View Source", and selecting the code that needs to be affected there.

Comment: I got the html from the inspect element in chrome. Ive updated my question with the html of the side menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this. Here is the code ive added:

```
ul.menu_sx li ul li.current.active_menu_yellow a{
    background-color: #FEEE9D !important;
}
```